Posgres: deadlock in upsert with ORDER BY clause
I have a concurrent upserts (more than one row in each of them) in the table in Postgres 15.5 and got deadlock.According to several answers in SO I need the ORDER BY clause, but I have it and it doesn't help. And I don't understand the reason why it happens.
Server logs:
Process 1090913 waits for ShareLock on transaction 125815480; blocked by process 1090917
Process 1090917: INSERT INTO ind_data (d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
SELECT d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id
FROM temp_ind_data_fact_2
ORDER BY d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id
ON CONFLICT (d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
DO UPDATE SET fact_2 = excluded.fact_2;
Process 1090913: INSERT INTO ind_data (d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
SELECT d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id
FROM temp_ind_data_fact_2
ORDER BY d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id
ON CONFLICT (d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
DO UPDATE SET fact_2 = excluded.fact_2;

Table SQL:
CREATE TABLE ind_data
(
    d_152_id integer NOT NULL,
    d_264_id integer NOT NULL,
    fact_1 double precision,
    fact_2 double precision,
    d_4032_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    d_1786_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT pk_ind_data PRIMARY KEY (d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
)

Temp table creating:
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_ind_data_fact_2 AS
SELECT d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id, fact_2
  FROM ind_data
 WHERE 1=2;

Temp table filling via COPY command.


I also tried to wrap in WITH but it didn't help
WITH data as (
SELECT d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id
  FROM temp_ind_data_fact_2
 ORDER BY d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
INSERT INTO ind_data (d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
SELECT d_152_id, d_264_id, fact_2, d_4032_id, d_1786_id
  FROM data
ON CONFLICT (d_152_id, d_264_id, d_4032_id, d_1786_id)
DO UPDATE SET fact_2 = excluded.fact_2;


ShareLock can be caused by CREATE INDEX. It is not acquired by rows update. Check was there some create index before the upsert

Please review [mre] and update the post with table DDL, example data, and additional execution context (e.g., the execution environment and any other statements within the same transactions as the INSERT statements).

@AterLux, indexes were not created
